# Hyperbola dimensions - intersections cone and plane

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, conic-sections, 3d

I’d like some help to understand how to derive the relationship of the intersection of a cone with a plane parallel to the cone axis. See below dimensions of the shapes involved.

[image]

What I want to define is shown in the next image.

[image]

The CAD is for illustration only as I'm doing these calculations on excel for multiple dimensions. So, I can define the height of the red-dotted shape (on the intersection), which is 3.122-1.1, but not sure how to get the length of that shape (I think is a hyperbola but not sure).

Any ideas? Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: You should include the images on the post.

Comment: They’re there. Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the base of the cone has diameter $D$ , and its height is $H$, then its semi-vertical angle is

$ \theta_c = \tan^{-1}\left( \dfrac{D}{2H}\right) $

The equation of the surface of the cone assuming the origin is at its apex is

$ x^2 + y^2  - z^2 \tan^2 \theta_c = 0 $

Cutting it with the plane $ x = x_0 $ (where $x_0 = 15.95$) results in the hyperbola

$   z^2 \tan^2 \theta_c  - y^2 = x_0^2  $

Setting $ z = - H + \Delta z $ , where $\Delta z = 1.1 $, we get

$ (- H + \Delta z)^2 \tan^2 \theta_c - y^2 = x_0 ^ 2 $

Therefore the distance that you want is given by

$ \Delta y = 2 \sqrt{ ( - H + \Delta z)^2 \tan^2 \theta_c - x_0 ^ 2 } $

Which can be re-written as

$\Delta y = 2 \sqrt{ ( - H + \Delta z)^2 \left(\dfrac{D} { 2 H} \right)^2 - x_0 ^ 2 } $

Using $ H = 35.04 , D = 35.04 ,  x_0 = 15.95 , \Delta z = 1.1 $ results in

$\Delta y = 2 \sqrt{ ( - 35.04 + 1.1)^2 \left(\dfrac{35.04} {70.08} \right)^2 - 15.95 ^ 2 } = \boxed{11.59}$

Comment: Thank you!! I did the calculations again and I gave you the wrong dimensions. I've updated the image.

Comment: I've update my solution with the new figures.